# reconocimiento de acentos con subprocess

Tags: python, firewall

Estoy utilizando subprocess con python para obtener las reglas del firewall, pero el output que tengo no reconoce los caracteres con acentos. ¿Por qué es esto y como podría solucionarlo?

El código que tengo es este

```
command = 'netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name= "all"'
output = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
print(output)
```

Al imprimir el output me arroja líneas como las siguientes:

Direcci¢n:                            Dentro

Acci¢n:                               Permitir

No sé si sea relevante pero al ejecutar el código directo en cmd los caracteres aparecen correctamente.

Comment: as intentado pasarle, `encoding`?

Comment: Probe con Windows-1252, None y utf-8. Las primeras dos no cambian el resultado y con utf-8 me da el siguiente error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 49: invalid start byte